# Number of ways to choose 6 cards with the same suit from a normal deck of cards

Tags: probability, permutations

In how many ways can one choose 6 cards from a normal deck of cards so as to have all suits present?
One way was $\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}$ but it involves repetition of cases.
Other way is total - anti-cases which is quite lengthy.
Is there any elegant way to solve this?

Comment: 52c6-[(4c1*13c6)+(4c2(13c5*13c1+13c4*13c2+13c3*13c3+13c2*13c4+13c1*13c5))    +(4c3(13c3*13c2*13c1*3!+13c4*13c1*13c1*3))]

Comment: What does 13c1 stand for? You may want to consult the [MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to increase readability of your question.

Comment: 13c1 out of 13 select 1,it is combination operator ,,NcR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two cases must be discerned:

1) from $1$ of the $4$ suits $3$ cards are chosen.

Leading to: $$\binom{4}{1}\times\binom{13}{3}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}$$ possibilities.

2) from $2$ of the $4$ suits $2$ cards are chosen.

Leading to: $$\binom{4}{2}\times\binom{13}{2}\binom{13}{2}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}$$ possibilities.